# Superset : Where to force an autologin

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-superset

I am using superset 0.20.4

If I want to add a token to my URL to autologin to a specific user
superset/dashboard/3?standalone=true&token=123456789

Where in the codes should I add a check on the token to login and force a user login action?
something like :
if request.args.get('token') == '123456789':
login user xxx

How can I autologin ?
I see lots of g.user being called but I don't see where the actual login process is being made.
Where did the username/password/csrf_token get used to authenticate the user?

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for anonymous/Public access to your dashboard, you should look into the Public role - which is documented here: 
https://superset.incubator.apache.org/security.html#public

and further here:
https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#role-based

If you have more sophisticated requirements, you should look into Flask App Builder (aka FAB) security model -which is documented here https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html- (Superset is a FAB app).

You can in particular override `SecurityManager` (from `flask_appbuilder.security.sqla.manager`).

In your specific case -where you're trying to auto-login users based on a token- it seems you might instead just be able to parse/verify the token and invoke `auth_user_db` (see `BaseSecurityManager`) in some view that doesn't require `@has_access` (see `class AuthDBView` in flask_appbuilder/security/views.py)